# Different y axes per row, but otherwise equal row-wise y axes in column and row faceted plotly chart

Tags: python, plotly

This is a problem I encounter very often. I have a plotly figure with column and row facets. I have already unlinked the y axes using `fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)`. However, while this is useful to scale axes between rows 1 and 2 as they exist in quite different domains, it breaks the ability to compare among column facets. You can see this issue in the plot below:

[image: Example]

So my question is, how can I have the same y axes across all column facets in each row, while having different y axes for row 1 and row 2?

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

The following Python code performs the row-wise matching automatically.
It matches all yaxes within the same row with the yaxis of the first column in that row.

```py
nb_rows = ... # the number of rows in your plot
nb_cols = ... # the number of columns in your plot
for row in range(nb_rows):
    match_y = "y" if row == 0 else f"y{row * nb_cols + 1}"
    for col in range(nb_cols):
        fig.update_yaxes(matches=match_y, row=row + 1, col=col + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure a `row-wise matching` you'll have to specify the following for the first row:

```
fig.layout.yaxis.matches = 'y'
fig.layout.yaxis2.matches = 'y'
fig.layout.yaxis3.matches = 'y'
```

And this for the second:

```
fig.layout.yaxis4.matches = 'y4'
fig.layout.yaxis5.matches = 'y4'
fig.layout.yaxis6.matches = 'y4'
```

As you can see, all y-axes are tied to the first y-axis of each corresponding row.

For those of you who would like to try it out, here's an example that builds on a [facet plot](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/)

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter(df, x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', color='continent', size='pop',
                facet_col='year', facet_col_wrap=4)

fig.layout.yaxis.matches = 'y'
fig.layout.yaxis2.matches = 'y'
fig.layout.yaxis3.matches = 'y'
fig.layout.yaxis4.matches = 'y'

fig.layout.yaxis5.matches = 'y5'
fig.layout.yaxis7.matches = 'y5'
fig.layout.yaxis6.matches = 'y5'
fig.layout.yaxis8.matches = 'y5'

fig.layout.yaxis9.matches = 'y9'
fig.layout.yaxis10.matches = 'y9'
fig.layout.yaxis11.matches = 'y9'
fig.layout.yaxis12.matches = 'y9'

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
nrows = df.row_var.nunique() # or find a way to get number of rows from fig object.. 
for i in range(0,nrows):
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=True, matches=f'y{i+1}', col=i+1)
```

https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/147#issuecomment-537814046

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've come across this need quite a lot, so I condensed different solutions into a function and documented it for y'all, making it useable out of the (code) box (Python>=3.10):

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, TypeAlias

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly._subplots import SubplotRef
grid_ref_: TypeAlias = List[List[Tuple[SubplotRef]]]


def realign_subplot_axes(
    fig: go.Figure,
    x_axes: bool | dict = False,
    y_axes: bool | dict = False
) -> None:
    """For a given plotly figure, allow all x-axes (column-wise) and/or y-axes (row-wise) to have
    their own ranges. The function operates in-place, modifying the figure without returning it.

    Args:
        fig: The plotly figure to be modified.
        x_axes, y_axes:
            If True, the respective axes will be realigned.
            If a dictionary, they will additionally be updated with the specified settings.

    Examples:

        realign_subplot_axes(fig, y_axes=True)
        realign_subplot_axes(fig, x_axes=dict(showticklabels=True))
    """
    if not (x_axes or y_axes):
        return
    subplot_rows: grid_ref_ = fig._grid_ref  # a list of lists, indicative of the grid dimensions
    n_cols: int = len(subplot_rows[0])       # needed in either case
    if x_axes:
        x_settings = x_axes if isinstance(x_axes, dict) else None
        for col in range(1, n_cols+1):
            # set the layout.xaxis.matches property of all subplots in the same column to the
            # x-axis name of the first subplot in that column. 'x1' is accepted for 'x' (the very first).
            fig.update_xaxes(x_settings, col=col, matches=f"x{col}")
    if y_axes:
        y_settings = y_axes if isinstance(y_axes, dict) else None
        n_rows = len(subplot_rows)
        for row in range(1, n_rows+1):
            # set the layout.yaxis.matches property of all subplots in the same row to the
            # y-axis name of the first subplot in that row. Y-axis names are numbered row-wise,
            # such that the first y-axis in the second row is 'y3' (if there are 2 columns).
            first_y = (row-1) * n_cols + 1
            fig.update_yaxes(y_settings, row=row, matches=f"y{first_y}")


df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(
    df,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    color='time',
    facet_col="sex",
    facet_row="day"
)
fig.write_image("default.png")
realign_subplot_axes(fig, y_axes=True)
fig.write_image("y_axes.png")
realign_subplot_axes(fig, x_axes=dict(showticklabels=True))
fig.write_image("both_axes.png")
```

**default.png** all plots share the same ranges
[image: default.png]
**y_axes.png** rows share y-axis ranges
[image: y_axes.png]
**both_axes.png** columns share x-axis ranges and show all x-ticks
[image: y_axes.png with x-ticks for each subplot]